# React reuable buttons with different functions

Tags: reactjs, button

I am in the process of trying to implement different functions in a reusable button component.

I'm working in this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-keller-3xnyk6?file=/src/App.js

I would like the functionality in the last two buttons in the first two buttons

would appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>
    {message}
    {count}
  </h1>

  <Button
    text="like ❤️"
    handleClick={function () {
      count >=0 && setMessage("like ❤️");
      increase();
    }}
  />

  <Button
    text="unlike "
    handleClick={function () {
      count < 0 && setMessage("unlike ");
      decrease();
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
    text="like ❤️"
    handleClick={function () {
      increase();
    }}
  />
  {/* counter */}
  <span className="count" contenteditable="true" onBlur={onCountEdit}>
    {count}
  </span>

  <Button
    text="unlike "
    handleClick={function () {
      count > 0 && decrease();
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an update to your question, or an answer? In the first case, please delete this and edit your question instead. In the second case, please read [answer], then [edit] this to clarify.